# Имя не определено

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside

используются 2 файла питона из одного импортируются функция
но в терминале вывод почему то что имя не определенно хотя функция исправна

инициализация переменной

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Breeze')
    main_win = open_ui_file("form.ui")
    main_win.show()
    win = open_ui_file("dialog.ui")
```

[image: Почему может писать что имя не определенно]

```
fn = str(win.lineEdit_2.text())
NameError: name 'win' is not defined
```

Comment: А где вообще присваивается переменная `win`? Если в какой-то функции, то вызываете ли вы эту функцию?

Comment: переменная win содержит в себе окно приложения

Comment: Это прекрасно. И всё же где эта переменная инициализируется? Лучше приложите код в виде текста, в том числе тот, который инициализирует эту переменную.

Comment: этого куска кода хватит ?

Comment: разумеется, этго куска кода не хватит. Это все равно что прийти к врачу с жалобой на боль в горле, но показывать ему не горло, а коленку.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему, в том числе и модули `form.ui`, `dialog.ui`

Comment: @Эникейщик А может и хватит ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А, ну в принципе всё понятно. Вы вообще в курсе, зачем пишется такая проверка?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    win = open_ui_file("dialog.ui")
```

Эта проверка работает так, что когда вы запускаете именно этот файл (где находится эта проверка), то этот `if` сработает. А если вы подключаете файл с этой проверкой как библиотеку, то этот `if` не работает. Это специально так задумано, чтобы можно было использовать через `include` функции из тех скриптов, которые могут запускаться и самостоятельно.

У вас ведь этот код в том файле, который вы подключаете через `include`? Вот этот кусок кода и не работает и у вас нет в результате этой переменной.

Вы лучше вынесите код инициализации окна в отдельную функцию и запускайте эту функцию где вам нужно - в частности в этом `if`, но и в том файле, в который вы подключаете этот код вы эту функцию тогда тоже сможете запустить и получить там эту переменную.

Comment: спасибо. я уже разобрался что в этом была загвоздка